# Convergence of logarithmic sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Numerical experimentations strongly suggest that the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)$$ converges and the limit is $\approx0\mathrm.7885$. Could someone give me a hint on a formal proof of convergence?

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right) = \frac{1}{n}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right) \sim \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: You could try to use Cauchy condensation test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Great hint. Got it, thank you!

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM You were the first one to suggest this and I actually like your idea the most. If you write it down as an answer, I’ll accept it.

Comment: @triple_sec I've written something

Comment: You have a very creative username! Did you intend it to refer to the [liqueur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_sec) or the [trinogometric ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#sec), or both? :)

Comment: @hypergeometric Thank you, this is very kind of you. This is just an alias I frequently use online. I do like the liquor, but I hadn’t thought about the connection to the secant function. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right) = \frac{1}{n}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right) \sim \frac{1}{n^2}$$

That's enough to intuitively confirm convergence.

The bound $\frac{1}{n}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\leq \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$ gives a formal proof.

Answer (score 3):

By summation by parts,
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}{n+1} = \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\log n}{n(n+1)}=2\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\log\left(n!\right)}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$
and the series in the middle term is obviously convergent. It can be written as:
$$ \left.\frac{d}{ds}\int_{0}^{1}\left(-x+\text{Li}_{1-s}(x)\right)\,dx\;\right|_{s=0^+}$$
or as:
$$ -\zeta'(2)+\zeta'(3)-\zeta'(4)+\zeta'(5)+\ldots\approx \color{red}{0.78853}. $$
$\log n<\sqrt{\log(n)\log(n+1)}$ and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality give:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\log n}{n(n+1)}<-\zeta'(2) $$
but that is not much stronger than the trivial:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n+1}<\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1.$$

Comment: All I needed is to show convergence, so I’m fine with the trivial upper bound. Thank you very much for this sharper estimate nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

hint: $a_n < \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}$

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The straight forward Limit Comparison Test should also work. Using LeGrandDODUM's comment, use the convergent Series $Bn=\frac{1}{n^2}$ and verify through LCT that you are essentially taking a limit $n ln(\frac{n}{n-1})$ where n goes to infinity. Since this is essentially an "infinity times zero" situation, but the $n$ term in the denominator as $\frac{1}{n}$ and proceed with L'Hospital's Rule to find (after some elementary algebra) the limit going to 1. This confirms the given series to be convergent.

Comment: Instead of L’Hôpital’s rule, how about
$$n\log\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)=-\log\left[\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n\right]\to-\log\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)=1?$$

Comment: Ah,  an approach through the limit of $e$, even nicer!....Either way, my point was to show that using the Limit Comparison Test is a relatively easy tool that (I think) addresses your question well...

Comment: @imranfar Yes, limit comparison it is. For some reason, I had failed to notice this convenient upper estimate. Thank you very much!